# How to resize image if max_width exceeds x with PIL?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am using the Django-resized library for automatically resizing images that are uploaded.  The issue I'm having is that when the image is resized, there is a dip in image quality despite setting quality to 100.  I don't know enough about PIL to mess around with this code, and I'm not sure how to increase the IQ, so what I'd like to do is put in a conditional that says if image width > 600 then resize image (that way images within a certain width don't get resized and take a hit in IQ).  My question is, should I put the if condition inside the constructor for ResizedImageField?  OR should I put it inside the save method in ResizedImageFileField?

DJANGO MODEL

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    image = ResizedImageField(max_width=500, max_height=300, upload_to='whatever')
```

DJANGO-RESIZED FORMS.PY

```
import os
try:
    from PIL import Image, ImageFile
except ImportError:
    import Image, ImageFile

try:
    # python3
    from io import BytesIO as StringIO
except ImportError:
    # python2
    from StringIO import StringIO

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

try:
    from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
except ImportError:
    from django.db.models import ImageField


DEFAULT_SIZE = getattr(settings, 'DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_SIZE', [1920, 1080])
DEFAULT_COLOR = (255, 255, 255, 0)


class ResizedImageFieldFile(ImageField.attr_class):

    def save(self, name, content, save=True):
        new_content = StringIO()
        content.file.seek(0)
        thumb = Image.open(content.file)
        thumb.thumbnail((
            self.field.max_width,
            self.field.max_height
            ), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        if self.field.use_thumbnail_aspect_ratio:
            img = Image.new("RGBA", (self.field.max_width, self.field.max_height), self.field.background_color)
            img.paste(thumb, ((self.field.max_width - thumb.size[0]) / 2, (self.field.max_height - thumb.size[1]) / 2))
        else:
            img = thumb

        try:
            img.save(new_content, format=thumb.format, **img.info)
        except IOError:
            ImageFile.MAXBLOCK = img.size[0] * img.size[1]
            img.save(new_content, format=thumb.format, **img.info)

        new_content = ContentFile(new_content.getvalue())

        super(ResizedImageFieldFile, self).save(name, new_content, save)


class ResizedImageField(ImageField):

    attr_class = ResizedImageFieldFile

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, **kwargs):
        //if self.max_width > 400:
        self.max_width = kwargs.pop('max_width', DEFAULT_SIZE[0])
        self.max_height = kwargs.pop('max_height', DEFAULT_SIZE[1])
        self.use_thumbnail_aspect_ratio = kwargs.pop('use_thumbnail_aspect_ratio', False)
        self.background_color = kwargs.pop('background_color', DEFAULT_COLOR)
        super(ResizedImageField, self).__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs) 


try:
    from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
    rules = [
        (
            (ResizedImageField,),
            [],
            {
                "max_width": ["max_width", {'default': DEFAULT_SIZE[0]}],
                "max_height": ["max_height", {'default': DEFAULT_SIZE[1]}],
                "use_thumbnail_aspect_ratio": ["use_thumbnail_aspect_ratio", {'default': False}],
                "background_color": ["background_color", {'default': DEFAULT_COLOR}],
            },
        )
    ]
    add_introspection_rules(rules, ["^django_resized\.forms\.ResizedImageField"])
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: PIL isn't terribly good at resizing, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113163/antialias-vs-bicubic-in-pilpython-image-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly not pretty.  I realize I have a lot of repeated code, but this is the only way I could figure out how to make it work.

```
class ResizedImageFieldFile(ImageField.attr_class):

    def save(self, name, content, save=True): 
        new_content = StringIO()
        content.file.seek(0)
        thumb = Image.open(content.file)

        if thumb.size[0] > 900:
            thumb.thumbnail((
                self.field.max_width,
                self.field.max_height
                ), Image.ANTIALIAS)

            if self.field.use_thumbnail_aspect_ratio:
                img = Image.new("RGBA", (self.field.max_width, self.field.max_height), self.field.background_color)
                img.paste(thumb, ((self.field.max_width - thumb.size[0]) / 2, (self.field.max_height - thumb.size[1]) / 2))
            else:
                img = thumb

            try:
                img.save(new_content, format=thumb.format, **img.info)
            except IOError:
                ImageFile.MAXBLOCK = img.size[0] * img.size[1]
                img.save(new_content, format=thumb.format, **img.info)
        else:
            img = thumb
            try:
                img.save(new_content, format=thumb.format, **img.info)
            except IOError:
                ImageFile.MAXBLOCK = img.size[0] * img.size[1]
                img.save(new_content, format=thumb.format, **img.info)

        new_content = ContentFile(new_content.getvalue())

        super(ResizedImageFieldFile, self).save(name, new_content, save)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like django-resized isn't providing a `quality` argument when saving. This argument will be ignored for other image formats than JPEG so you can always pass it without any worry.

If using pillow (the PIL fork), you can use `quality='keep'` to use the same quantization table as the original image. Otherwise you can explicitly specify the quality percentage as an integer (don't use 100, it creates obtusely large images).

Comment: Yea I forgot to include it in the code, but I am able to save with quality 100%, what I'm trying to figure out now is where to put an if condition

Comment: I'd put it inside the save method.

Comment: I'm at work so I can't try it out right now, but should i just wrap the entire contents of the save method inside the if condition?  See my answer I posted below.

Comment: So if the width does NOT exceed 800 px, the image save should perform like a standard ImageField with no added parameters.  (At least that's what I'm hoping for)

Comment: I figured it out, it's definitely not pretty though hah.